# pygccxml on python 3.0+ or Python 2.7+?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I will be using pygccxml to parse C++ header files.

Does this module work with Python 3.0+ (i.e. have you used it without issues on this version of python)?

The reason I ask is that python 3.0+ is backwards-incompatible and i want to know if I need to run python 2.7+ or if I can go with the newer 3.0+.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try it? If it hasn't been ported it's unlikely to even install.

The lack of mention of Python 3 is however a pretty big indication that it hasn't been ported, and since it hasn't had one single release since Python 3 was released I'd say you probably have to use Python 2.

(Edit: I downloaded it and tried. Took a minute. No, it's not ported.)

Comment: Thanks Lennart. I beat you to it ;)